# SDL2/_real_SDL_config.h: No such file or directory

Tags: cmake, g++, windows-subsystem-for-linux, sdl-2

I have been trying to set up SDL2 on a WSL (Ubuntu) and cross compile to windows using cmake and mingw. I ran into this problem where it fails trying to compile the library files themselves:

```
                 from /usr/include/SDL2/SDL_main.h:25,
                 from /usr/include/SDL2/SDL.h:32,
                 from /mnt/c/users/user/repos/project/final.cpp:5:
/usr/include/SDL2/SDL_config.h:4:10: fatal error: SDL2/_real_SDL_config.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <SDL2/_real_SDL_config.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Here is my CmakeLists.txt

```
project(name)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)            # Enable c++14 standard
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${name_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakePath")
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)
set(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX x86_64-w64-mingw32)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}-g++)


set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH /usr/${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX})

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)t
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)

set(SOURCE_FILES final.cpp Soldier.cpp TilesEnum.cpp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} --static -std=c++0x -o test")

#add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/test.cpp)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
find_package(SDL2_image REQUIRED)

include_directories(${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIR}
                    ${SDL2_IMAGE_INCLUDE_DIR}
                    ${SDL2_TTF_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(name ${SDL2_LIBRARY}
                             ${SDL2_IMAGE_LIBRARIES}
                             ${SDL2_TTF_LIBRARIES})

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static-libgcc")
```

My running theory so far is I installed the wrong library, but that doesn't explain why it wouldn't compile at all. I am very lost. I couldn't find anything with this specific problem, please link me to something similar if there is.

Comment: Setting things like `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` after the `project()` call is **wrong**. These settings normally performed in the **toolchain file**, which is used via `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=path/to/file` option for `cmake`. I would suggest to read CMake documentation about toolchains: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html.

Comment: That fixed this issue thank you so much! Now need to figure out how to find only static libraries as I want to run this on something that doesn't have the libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things wrong with this CMake file with a lot of repeated code. Tsyvarev's comment helped fix this a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`fatal error: SDL2/_real_SDL_config.h` this means there is no SDL2 library installed on your system, then, you cannot compile

- SDL_config.h (64 bit)
- _real_SDL_config.h (32 bit)

Just install the 32 bits version of SDL2 lib: `sudo apt install libsdl2-dev:i386`